# XPages extlib oneui layout - How to add placebar actions dynamically

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to add actions dynamically in PlaceBar (extlib oneui application layout).

We have couple of urls stored in some configuration documents. Based on these URLs I want to create Container node having Basic Child nodes in it. Every child node use one URL from list. 
How I can create container node and add child nodes to it dynamically? any sample SSJS/Java/CSJS code for this?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the quick reply. This is very useful information for me.

Another way I found out based on XSnippet code and some reverse engg. from java code in xpage as follow :

```
var oneui = getComponent("applicationLayout1");
var uiConfig = oneui.getConfiguration();
var containerNode:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexContainerTreeNode = new com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexContainerTreeNode();
containerNode.setLabel("Cluster Applications");

var docAppProfile = docColl.getFirstDocument();
while(docAppProfile != null)
{
    var children:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexLeafTreeNode = new com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.complex.ComplexLeafTreeNode();
    children.setComponent(oneui);
    children.setLabel(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appTitle"));
    children.setHref(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appURL"));
    children.setImage(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appLogoThumb"));
    containerNode.addChild(children);

    children = null;
    var tempDoc = docColl.getNextDocument(docAppProfile);
    docAppProfile = null;
    docAppProfile = tempDoc;
}
uiConfig.addPlaceBarAction(containerNode);
```

This is sample code only. Converted this is into java code and serialized to improve performance and load it only once in application.

Thank you again for help.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the Repeat Node (`xe:repeatTreeNode`) which is described in the XPages Extension Library book on page 245.

Here's a very simple example (taken directly from the book):

```
<xe:repeatTreeNode var="val">
   <xe:this.value>
      <![CDATA[#{javascript:return [
        ["Home","home"],
        ["Domino","domino"],
        ["OneUI","oneui"]
      ];}]]>
   </xe:this.value>
   <xe:this.children>
      <xe:basicLeafNode>
         <xe:this.submitValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:return val[1]}]]></xe:this.submitValue>
         <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:return val[0]}]]></xe:this.label>
      </xe:basicLeafNode>
   </xe:this.children>
</xe:repeatTreeNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

basically its the same code you listed above, but in Java.  and then this small code in the faces-config.xml file

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.company.app.phaselisteners.PlaceBarInjector</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>

package com.company.app.phaselisteners;





public class PlaceBarInjector implements PhaseListener {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        UIComponent oneui = JSFUtil.findComponent("applicationLayout1");
    Configruation uiconfig = oneui.getConfiguration();
    ComplexContainerTreeNode containerNode = new ComplexContainerTreeNode();
    containerNode.setLabel("Cluster Applications");

    Document docAppProfile = docColl.getFirstDocument();
    while(docAppProfile != null)
    {
            ComplexLeafTreeNode children = new ComplexLeafTreeNode();
            children.setComponent(oneui);
            children.setLabel(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appTitle"));
        children.setHref(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appURL"));
            children.setImage(docAppProfile.getItemValueString("appLogoThumb"));
            containerNode.addChild(children);

            Document tempDoc = docColl.getNextDocument(docAppProfile);
            docAppProfile = tempDoc;
    }
    uiConfig.addPlaceBarAction(containerNode);
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("END PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is use a PhaseListener to inject the Items into your Container Node before render response.  Then you could control it in a single place for all of your pages.

Comment: Calling a SSJS function in Per's example would do too for all pages or, as recommended, put the layout into a custom control and use that everywhere. But a phase listener for sure would be an interesting exercise

Comment: Hello Toby, do you have any sample code for the way to inject items into PhaseListener? please let me know. Thanks.